# Entity Framework CompatibleWithModel(true) returns negative false

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I am migrating EF from DB first to Code First.
So far its OK except one strange moment.
Initial DB contains Views and stored Functions and Procedures.
Just switching to EF Code First approach using existing DB is fine.

But creating new DB if it is not existing causes some problems.

- Automatic Migrations are OFF.
- Initial migration to create DB is added and UP method is modified to use this.Sql() method to create stored functions/procedures and Views.
- context constructor is modified next way:

  ```
      if (Database.Exists() == false)
      {
          Database.SetInitializer<MyDbContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<MyDbContext>());
      }
      else
      {
          if (Database.CompatibleWithModel(true) == false)
          {
              Database.SetInitializer<MyDbContext>(new Initializers.MyDbContextInitializer());
          }
          else
          {
              Database.SetInitializer<MyDbContext>(null);
          }
      }
      Database.Initialize(false);
  ```

And here comes the magic. After Initial migration run and DB is created 
the execption saying:

> Unable to update database to match the current model because there are
>   pending changes and automatic migration is disabled. Either write the
>   pending model changes to a code-based migration or enable automatic
>   migration. Set DbMigrationsConfiguration.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled to
>   true to enable automatic migration. You can use the Add-Migration
>   command to write the pending model changes to a code-based migration.
>   CompatibleWithModel(true)  returns negative false. Investigating
>   around and under debugger just set next statement to else part( like
>   if model is compatible) and every thing works well.

In Package Manager Console: Add-Migration MissingStuff
Creates migration that only does recreate Foreign keys for each key DB has.

```
Up()
{
...
DropForeignKey("dbo.MST_UserRegion", "RegionID", "dbo.MST_Region");
AddForeignKey("dbo.MST_UserRegion", "RegionID", "dbo.MST_Region", "RegionID");
...
}
Down()
{
 ...
   DropForeignKey("dbo.MST_UserRegion", "RegionID", "dbo.MST_Region");
   AddForeignKey("dbo.MST_UserRegion", "RegionID", "dbo.MST_Region", "RegionID", cascadeDelete: true);
 ...
}
```

moreover generated Down() is wrong and causes error since FKs initially created as "NO action" in initial migration Up() method.
example:

```
CreateTable(
    "MST_UserRegion",
    c => new
        {
            UserRegionID = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 20),
            RegionID = c.Int(nullable: false),
            UserId = c.Int(nullable: false),
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.UserRegionID)
    .ForeignKey("MST_Region", t => t.RegionID, cascadeDelete: false)
    .ForeignKey("MST_User", t => t.UserId, cascadeDelete: false)
    .Index(t => t.RegionID)
    .Index(t => t.UserId);
```

So FKs are not a problem since second migration does really nothing.
My suspect is that EF generates wrong Migration hash for migrations containing in Up() method usage of this.Sql(@"CRATE VIEW XXX AS ...")

As work around I can simply just remove any code from Up and Down methods of generated second migration and run it to cause context hash will match Hash in __MigrationHistory table.

If someone had same issue could you please share it? Just wonder if my suspect about using Migration.Sql() method is correct. May be I am doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**
If after DB creation ignore result of if (Database.CompatibleWithModel(true) == false) and force execution of Database.SetInitializer(null); It works as expected without errors. So really problem is Database.CompatibleWithModel() result.

**UPDATE2:**

- Save Model value of second migration.
- Delete second migration from project.
- Drop DB and recreate DB using initial migration only
- Manually update Model value of __MigrationHistory using values save in first step.

  Results correct work of application.

Comment: The Migration does 2 things:
- adds the FK's whic hmight indicate a changed realation
- EF Migrations also stores metadata of your model in teh database, which is used to check if the model is installed. If this entry is not within the database, EF knows that there is a missing entry/the current model is not installed. By Setting the initializer to null this does not get checked. It seems in your current case that from the DB SChemas perspective it is a compatible Change, but if you have other changes this might not be the case (e.g. new columns, renames etc)

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you point. Initializer is set to 'null' only if current context is compatible with existing DB and there is not any action required.